# Find the reason why mysql root password is reset at ever system boot

Tags: linux, mysql, fedora-20, mysqld-safe

Every time when I restart the server, booting the system I have to the following error:

```
database error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can solve it by doing the following commands

```
service mysqld stop
su -c '/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=root &'
mysqld -u root mysql
update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD("my_password") where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

So what is the reason that at every system boot I have to run these commands?
and how to save these settings forever?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm thqt the mysql.sock file exists?  Maybe its being deleted at boot?

Comment: let me check that

Comment: @RyanGriggs yes, I confirm. mysql.sock file being deleted at boot.

Comment: Here's a really dumb question, but can you confirm that mysqld is actually being started at boot? (chkconfig, also ps aux | grep mysqld) the mysql.sock file is supposed to be created each time the mysqld server starts. So next step, check logs to ensure it's starting without errors.

Comment: Is it illegal to ask dumb quesition? :) Hey, Ryan, think twice, maybe your answer is more dumber than my quesition? I will find out by myself thank you :)

Comment: You misunderstood. I was saying my question was dumb. Not yours.  Good luck.